# Specific issue with reading data

Tags: observablehq

I am not sure why the data is not loading in?? It was working fine before, then all of a sudden any file I try to read in just returns async

INPUT: data = FileAttachment("cincinnati_store.json").json

OUTPUT FROM CELL: data = async ƒ(…)

Comment: hi can you add more info? maybe a link to your notebook,?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need parentheses after `.json`. So, the input of the cell should look like:

```js
data = FileAttachment("cincinnati_store.json").json()
```

You need the parentheses because `json` is a method on the FileAttachment (i.e. a function you have to call). That’s as opposed to something like the `length` of a JavaScript array, which is a property of the object, so you can just call `myArray.length` without parentheses. It’s fair to be confused by this — different objects do it differently, so you sort of just have to know (or look up) what’s what!

You get a hint there in the output of the cell (the “inspector”) because it’s telling you that the value of what you’ve put in is an asynchronous function. It’s showing you the function itself, as opposed to the return value of calling the function, so you can tell that you have to call it to get the Promise that resolves to your `cincinnati_store.json` data.

If that doesn’t work, if you post a link to your notebook I’d be happy to take a look.